# Play Framework: Trouble with views in modules

Tags: playframework-2.0

Look at the directory layout of my Play application:

```
myApp
  └ app
     └ controllers
     └ models
     └ views
         └ myView1.scala.html
         └ main.scala.html
  └ modules
     └ auth
        └ app
           └ controllers
           └ models
           └ views 
               └ myView2.scala.html
               └ main.scala.html
```

The problem is that it looks like `myView2.scala.html` calls `main` in `myApp/views/main.scala.html` instead of `main` in `myApp/modules/auth/views/main.scala.html`... and if I remove `myApp/modules/auth/views/main.scala.html`, then `myView2.scala.html`does not compile.

That said, how do I reference either of the two `main` explicitly? Any help would be really appreciated - I'm getting crazy. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think is better to put the modules views in a subpackage like:

> myApp/modules/auth/views/auth/main.scala.html